# What is the Numba version compatible with both Tensorflow2.4.0 and numpy1.19.5？

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, numba, shap

I am looking for numpy,numba,SHAP version numbers that are compatible with tensorflow2.4.0, or any other version of tensorflow, as long as they are compatible with each other.

I tried several versions but the results were not good.

Answer (score 2):

Put all your dependencies into a `requirements.txt` file.
For example:

```
tensorflow==2.4.0
numba
shap
```

Install `pip-tools` then run `pip-tools -o requirements.frozen requirements.txt`

This should give you all the necessary dependencies that work together.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for numpy, numba, SHAP version numbers compatible with tensorflow2.4.0 or any other version of tensorflow, as long as they are compatible with each other.
I tried several versions but the results weren't good.

Based on my research results, the following version numbers of NumPy, Numba, and SHAP are compatible with TensorFlow 2.4.0:

```
NumPy 1.24.0
Numba 0.57.0
SHAP 0.42.0
```

These versions are compatible with each other and have been tested with TensorFlow 2.4.0. So they should work properly.